# RHive connection error : rhive.connect()

Tags: r, hive

> rhive.connect(host="172.16.210.130",port=10000)
>   Warning: 
>       +----------------------------------------------------------+
>       + / hiveServer2 argument has not been provided correctly.  +
>       + / RHive will use a default value: hiveServer2=TRUE.      +
>       +----------------------------------------------------------+

15/11/05 07:54:41 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: 172.16.210.130:10000
15/11/05 07:54:41 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: 172.16.210.130:10000
15/11/05 07:54:41 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://172.16.210.130:10000/default
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [root] does not have [CREATE] privilege on [/r]

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution of issue:

Set permissions 777 on hfs directory and sub-directories

Changes to following files:

hive-site.xml (in both conf & conf.server dirs)

set:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
<property>
```

change:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
    <value> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.MetaStoreAuthzAPIAuthorizerEmbedOnly</value>
```

to

```
<property>
    <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider</value>
</property>
```

hiveserver2-site.xml (in both conf & conf.server directory)

set:

```
 <property>
     <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
     <value>false</value>
 </property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

set:

```
<property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
     <value>false</value>
</property>
```

SSH to sandbox and log into Hive as with hue user:

su hue

hive

Reference:
http://hortonworks11.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=7980721&item=4941

Answer (score 0):

Login as a hdfs or hive user

```
su hdfs
```

or

```
su hive
```

and then try your steps on R console.